# Charger problem for Phone purchased in US

Tags: iphone, power, charger

I purchased Iphone 6 in US, and would be coming back to India.
Which charger I should use here in India, as I know that there is a voltage difference in US and in India.

Answer (score 1):

The US USB charger that came with your iPhone can work anywhere between 100 and 240 volts, 50-60Hz (see [here](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MB974ZM/B/do-i-need-a-power-converter-to-charge-my-iphone-in-a-country-with-220-volt-power/QHU7PP7TF77AYY7DP)). The USB end should be 5V (DC) and 1 Amp (5 Watts) You could:

- Apple sells a [World Travel Adapter Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB974ZM/B/apple-world-travel-adapter-kit) which would suit your needs, but could be a bit pricey
- Most plugs that work in India that you can plug USB into, that meets the above specifications.
- use the charger the phone came with and buying a regular US / India adapter plug.